# Spring RestTemplate Jackson Deserialize Array of Arrays

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I'm using Spring RestTemplate to pull data from an API that returns an un-named array of arrays in the following format:

```
[
    [
        1518230040,
        8863.96,
        8876.95,
        8863.96,
        8876.94,
        1.81986441
    ],
    [
        1518229980,
        8851.03,
        8862.53,
        8853.79,
        8862.53,
        2.95533163
    ],
    [
        1518229920,
        8853.79,
        8855.3,
        8855.29,
        8853.8,
        3.0015851299999996
    ]
]
```

The indices in the nested arrays represent the following properties of a [Candlestick](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/candlestick.asp):

```
0 => time
1 => low
2 => high
3 => open
4 => close
5 => volume
```

For example, in the first nested array, the **time** of the Candlestick is 1518230040, the **low** is 8863.96, the **high** is 8876.95, the **open** is 8863.96, the **close** is 8876.94, and the **volume** is 1.81986441.

I'd like to map these nested array elements to Candlestick objects.  Below is my Candlestick class.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Candlestick {
    private long time;

    private BigDecimal low;

    private BigDecimal high;

    private BigDecimal open;

    private BigDecimal close;

    private BigDecimal volume;

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public BigDecimal getLow() {
        return low;
    }

    public void setLow(BigDecimal low) {
        this.low = low;
    }

    public BigDecimal getHigh() {
        return high;
    }

    public void setHigh(BigDecimal high) {
        this.high = high;
    }

    public BigDecimal getOpen() {
        return open;
    }

    public void setOpen(BigDecimal open) {
        this.open = open;
    }

    public BigDecimal getClose() {
        return close;
    }

    public void setClose(BigDecimal close) {
        this.close = close;
    }

    public BigDecimal getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(BigDecimal volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Candle [time=" + time + ", low=" + low + ", high=" + high + ", open=" + open + ", close=" + close
                + ", volume=" + volume + "]";
    }
}
```

How can I map the nested arrays to Candlestick objects using Spring RestTemplate and Jackson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designing a Custom Deserializer would be  a reasonable solution to this problem. But mapping array to an oject seems to be a tricky job. Keeping @shazin's idea as base, Custom Deserializer that maps array of arrays into list of objects can be written as follows:

```java
public class CStickListDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<ArrayList<Candlestick>> { 

    public CStickListDeserializer() { 
        this(null); 
    } 

    public CStickListDeserializer(Class<?> c) { 
        super(c); 
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Candlestick> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        Candlestick cs ;
        ArrayList<Candlestick> cList = new ArrayList<Candlestick>();
        BigDecimal[][] a = jp.readValueAs(BigDecimal[][].class);
        for(BigDecimal[] a1 : a){
            cs = new Candlestick();
            cs.setTime(a1[0].longValue());
            cs.setLow(a1[1]);
            cs.setHigh(a1[2]);
            cs.setOpen(a1[3]);
            cs.setClose(a1[4]);
            cs.setVolume(a1[5]); 
            cList.add(cs);
        }
             return cList;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```java
     ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
     SimpleModule mod = new SimpleModule();
     mod.addDeserializer(ArrayList.class, new CStickListDeserializer());
     om.registerModule(mod);
     ArrayList<Candlestick> CandlestickList = om.readValue(json, ArrayList.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the following;

1. Write a Custom Deserializer for Candlestick pojo Configure

   ```
   public class CandlestickDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Candlestick> { 

       public CandlestickDeserializer() { 
           this(null); 
       } 

       public CandlestickDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
           super(vc); 
       }

       @Override
       public Item deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
         throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
           JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
           // Read the Array or Arrays

           return new Candlestick(// Return with correct values read from Array);
       }
   }
   ```
2. ObjectMapper to use that custom Deserializer

   ```
   // This will get the Spring ObjectMapper singleton instance.
   @Autowired
   ObjectMapper mapper;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() throws Exception {
       SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
       module.addDeserializer(Candlestick.class, new CandlestickDeserializer());
       mapper.registerModule(module);
   }     


   Candlestick readValue = mapper.readValue(json, Candlestick.class);
   ```